# Должны ли совпадать адреса виртуальной функции в базовом класе и переопределенной в производном?

Tags: c++, ооп, адрес, виртуальная-функция

Поясните пожалуйста, если у меня есть виртуальный метод в базовом классе и я его переопределяю в производном, должны ли адреса этих методов совпадать? У меня есть базовый класс Book. В нем лежит виртуальная функция Show():

```
virtual void Show()
    {
        showISBN();
        showAuthor();
        showTitle();
    }
```

Есть производный класс CardFile, в котором я переопределяю Show():

```
void Show() override {
        Book::Show();
        cout << "Number of refuge: " << refugeNumber << endl;
        cout << "Stock: " << stock << endl;
    }
```

Далее в консоль я вывожу адреса методов таким вот образом:

```
printf("Book::Show -- %p\n", &Book::Show);
printf("CardFile::Show -- %p\n", &CardFile::Show);
```

Но получаю почему-то разные значения. Так и должно быть?

Comment: Так, а откуда вообще возник вопрос? На первый взгляд (даже если игнорировать написанное в моем ответе) вы печатаете адреса двух *разных* функций. Почему вас удивляет, что эти адреса отличаются???

Comment: Когда-то был вообще непонятный случай, когда адреса совпали. Это меня очень удивило...

Comment: @Andrey_Raf Ну если выводить их таким образом, то запросто могут совпасть. Дело в том, что указатель на метод класса не является обычным указателем и его нельзя распечатать через `%p`. Обычно это структура размеров раза в 3 больше обычного указателя. Так что его содержимое надо печатать побайтово `sizeof(&Book::Show)` байт.

Comment: @Andrey_Raf: "Адреса совпали" - это именно то, о чем я пишу в своем ответе. Но в общем случае об этих адресах ничего сказать нельзя.

Comment: Спасибо большое за пояснение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Ну, во-первых, печатать указатели на функции через `%p` формально не разрешается.)

Нет, не должны. Тут на самом деле ничего конкретного или предсказуемого не должно  быть. Значения указателя на виртуальную функцию неспецифицировано и результаты сравнения такого указателя на равенство с указателями на другие функции [неспецифицированы](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.eq#4.3).

> **7.6.10 Equality operators**
>   4 [...] Comparing pointers to members is defined as follows:
>   - If either is a pointer to a virtual member function, the result is unspecified.

Реальные причины такой ситуации заключаются в особенностях поведения указателей на виртуальные функции в С++: они никогда не привязываются к конкретным целевым функциям. Решение о том, какая виртуальная функция будет вызвана, принимается в момент вызова, а не в момент инициализации указателя.

Чтобы реализовать это поведение на практике, в традиционных реализациях указатель на виртуальную функцию обычно указывает не на саму функцию, а на скрытую промежуточную "функцию-вызывалку". Одна и та же "функция-вызывалка" может использоваться для разных виртуальных функций, в результате чего указатели на разные виртуальные функции могут иметь одно и то же физическое значение. И наоборот, для разных классов могут использоваться разные "функция-вызывалки", что приведет к разности указателей, даже если они в итоге вызывают одну и ту же виртуальную функцию.

Последняя деталь как и раз и объясняет наблюдаемое вами поведение.